# postgresql "insert ... on conflict ... update" how to specify which row to update from

Tags: postgresql, merge, upsert

I have no idea how to make this work, hope you can help me

I have a table "student_to_course_term" containing the columns "course_term_id", "student_id", "student_mc_worksheet_id" and "id"

What I want to achieve is to copy all rows with course_term_id=19 to new rows with course_term_id=23. If row already exists, update the "student_mc_worksheet_id".

This is my code so far, but I'm not sure how to access the row with course_term_id=19 and course_term_id=23 after the "on conflict do update set" part. Any help appreciated!

```
INSERT INTO public.student_to_course_term
(course_term_id, student_id, student_mc_worksheet_id)
SELECT 23, student_id, student_mc_worksheet_id
FROM public.student_to_course_term
WHERE course_term_id = 19
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT student_to_course_term_student_id_course_term_id_key
DO UPDATE
SET student_mc_worksheet_id ( =>from the student_mc_worksheet_id=23 row) = student_mc_worksheet_id ( => from the student_mc_worksheet_id=19 row) ;
```

Comment: You always update the "conflicting" row, and you can access the values that would have been inserted using using the alias `excluded`. So just use `set student_mc_worksheet_id = excluded.student_mc_worksheet_id`